# JS issue with dynamically appended slides

Tags: jquery, ajax, slider, append

I have an issue with my JQuery Slider. I use - [Swiper Slider](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WEaoBfmLREY)

It works fine, but when append slides dynamically, slider stops working.

Could you please help me to make it work with dynamically appended slides?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that...

I should have used swiper.appendSlide(); and swiper.update(); rather than jquery .append()

Thanks